# Ionic NFC makeReadyOnly() not working

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, nfc, phonegap

I wrote an App which is writing to a NFC-Tag and everything is working fine so far except the makeReadyOnly() function. Didn't find anyone with the same issue yet.

```
  nfcWriter(address: string) {

    let message = this.ndef.textRecord(address);
    let application = this.ndef.androidApplicationRecord("de.acc.anwesenheitsdokumentation");
    this.nfc.write([application, message]).then(() => {
      if (this.permanent == true) {
        console.log(NFC.installed());
        this.nfc.makeReadyOnly().then(() => {
          console.log("ReadOnly");
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }
      alert("erfolgreich geschrieben");
    })
      .catch(() => alert("konnte nicht geschrieben werden!"));
}
```

NFC.installed() return true, which means NFC plugin is installed, right?
 But the console log tells me this when i wanna do the function makeReadyOnly():

```
[14:52:24]  console.warn: Native: tried calling NFC.makeReadyOnly, but the NFC plugin is not installed. 
[14:52:24]  console.warn: Install the NFC plugin: 'ionic plugin add phonegap-nfc' 
[14:52:27]  console.log: plugin_not_installed
```

So yeah,... writing and reading everything works fine except this little function :(
Anyone has any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and I want to document the solution.

As far as I know this is currently a bug in the Ionic Native adaptaion of the Phonegap-NFC plugin.

> The solution for me was to go to **node_modules/@ionic-native/nfc**
>   in your project and replace every instance of **makeReadyOnly** with **makeReadOnly**.

When you look at the code for the Phonegap-NFC plugin, you see that the function name is supposed to be "makeReadOnly", not "makeReadyOnly".
 My guess is that the name mismatch is the cause of this error.